# How to decode ABI such that i get From, To, For in python

Tags: python, abi, abiencoderv2

Currently my implementations of abi decode gets only token amount and not the From, To, address and token amount is without decimal point

```
value = decode(['uint256'],log['data'])
```

ouptput

```
Token transfer details:
Value: (2657829493000000000000,)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't quite clear, but I'm assuming that `log['data']` is several bytes values concatenated, and that Value is an amount in wei. In that case you could use `eth_abi` and `web3.py` as below:

```py
from web3 import Web3
from eth_abi import encode, decode

accountA = '0xaAaAaAaaAaAaAaaAaAAAAAAAAaaaAaAaAaaAaaAa'
accountB = '0xbBbBBBBbbBBBbbbBbbBbbbbBBbBbbbbBbBbbBBbB'
wei_amt = 2657829493000000000000

w3 = Web3()

encoded = encode(['address', 'address', 'uint256'], [accountA, accountB, wei_amt])

print(encoded)

decoded = decode(['address', 'address', 'uint256'], encoded)

print(decoded)

address_from, address_to, token_amt_in_wei = decoded

amount_in_eth = w3.from_wei(token_amt_in_wei, "ether")

print(f"{address_from=}")
print(f"{address_to=}")
print(f"{amount_in_eth=}")
```